# Nest.js как правильно задать ApiHeader?

Tags: node.js, header, swagger, openapi, nestjs

Описываю ответ метода через `@nestjs/swagger`.
Хочу, чтобы в ui в графе "Media type" было видно, что сервер отвечает с заголовком `content-type: application/xml` (по умолчанию там пишут json).

Навесил декоратор `@Header('Content-Type', 'application/xml')` - swagger эту информацию не подхватывает.

Пытаюсь навесить декоратор `@ApiHeader` или прописать поле header в аргументе декоратора `@ApiResponse`. Но что туда передать, никак не пойму, тайпскрипт на все ругается.

Приведите пример пожалуйста.

Comment: https://github.com/nestjs/swagger/issues/626#issuecomment-606009188

Comment: https://docs.nestjs.com/openapi/decorators "All of the available OpenAPI decorators have an Api prefix"  https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/basic-structure/ https://swagger.io/specification/v2/

Comment: Stack Overflow на русском |>
Справка |>
Как публиковать ответы |> [Можно ли ответить на свой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: @qwabra а на чужой можно?

Comment: разрешаю ...........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После продолжительных экспериментов решаю вопрос навешиванием следующих декораторов:

```
@ApiOkResponse({content: {'application/xml': {example: carlistexResExample}}})
```

или

```
@ApiOkResponse({content: {'application/pdf': {}}})
```

P.S. что лежит в примере:

```
export const carlistexResExample: string = `<?xml version="1.0"?> ...`
```